# get handle of IE windows security dialog in c#

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, console-application

here is my requirement. I need to create small console app in c#. i will have its shortcut in quick launch.
whenever IE popups security dialog (see below) asking userid and password, i will invoke this application from quick launch and this application will fill userid and password in popup. can anyone guide me how to do that.

Actually during development i need to connect different servers (again and again) and all servers have different id and complicated psw. what i was thinking that i will have different instances of this application in my quicklauch for every server. this way everytime this dialog pops up all i need to do is to click a shortcut to logic. does it make sense??

[image]

Comment: If you're building a .NET app, you could embed FiddlerCore and have FiddlerCore do the authentication on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

try example

http://user:password@thewebsite.com

this will log in automatic if the user and password is correct
or send you error 401 if not correct

Comment: This syntax hasn't been supported in Internet Explorer since IE7.

Comment: i don't if it support sorry but what you are need to connect an ip or windows user if ip you can send request with user name and password

Answer (score -1):

Can you not store credenential in Windows vault? In this way you need not supply username/password again and again.

Comment: Thats what i am doing but my problem is that i have multiple credentials for each server. i use seperate credentials depending on purpose :(